# place span tag between anchor tag using Action Link Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I got website templates and using it for my website. I am new to asp.net mvc 3 and razor. It is very difficult to modify html tag using html helper. How can I place the span tag between anchor tag using ActionLink Helper. I have used razor and html helper for producing link. 
I want to produce following tags:

```
<li><a href="Account/LogOff" title="Logout"><span class="glyph logout"></span> Logout</a></li>
```

I have try this

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("<span class='glyph logout'></span> Log out", "LogOff", "Account") </li>
```

I am confuse how to do that. It is not the correct way that produces span tag as string. How can I produce correct tags.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to use is @Url.Action to create the URL while having your custom HTML.

```
<li>
  <a href="@Url.Action("LogOff","Account")" title="Logout">
    <span class="glyph logout"></span> Logout
  </a>
</li>
```

This way you have control over the URL and be able to add your own custom HTML. @Html.ActionLink doesn't allow you to add custom HTML inside the  tags natively.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to customize, what's inside your anchor tag, you should use the Html.Action method instead of the Html.ActionLink

```
<li>
  <a href="@Html.Action("LogOff", "Account")" title="Logout">
    <span class="glyph logout"></span> Log
  </a>
</li>
```